# On demand lazy loading via dynamic @JsonIgnore annotation

Tags: json, hibernate, jackson, lazy-loading

I have something like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "myEntity")
public class MyEntity {
  //....

  @Column(name = "content")
  private byte[] content;
  //....
}
```

**PROBLEM**:
I pass MyEntity to the client as JSON string.
But **the problem** is that I have **two types** of client's requests:

1. I need to pass MyEntity **with** *byte[] content* array
2. I need to pass MyEntity **without** *byte[] content* array

In first case I needn't @JsonIgnore annotation, in second - do need.

**QUESTIONS**:

1. How to achive dynamical @JsonIgnore annotation? Is it possible at all?
2. Any alternatives to achieve lazy loading?

P.S. As I understand, even if I mark my *byte[] content* array with lazy-load  annotation, it will be loaded anyway when Jackson will parse MyEntity to JSON-string.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can disable FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES feature on ObjectMapper object. After that, ObjectMapper should be able to deserialize JSON with this property and without it.

Comment: The problem is in serialization (when I serialazise the object with jackson, it pull all lazy-loadings), but not in deserialization

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Jackson views](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews). Please, see my below example:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonView;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class JacksonProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Entity entity = new Entity();
        entity.setId(100);
        entity.setContent(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 });

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        System.out.println("Generate JSON with basic properties: ");
        System.out.println(objectMapper.writerWithView(View.BasicView.class).writeValueAsString(entity));
        System.out.println("Generate JSON with all properties: ");
        System.out.println(objectMapper.writerWithView(View.ExtendedView.class).writeValueAsString(entity));
    }
}

interface View {

    interface BasicView {
    }

    interface ExtendedView extends BasicView {
    }
}

class Entity {

    @JsonView(View.BasicView.class)
    private int id;

    @JsonView(View.ExtendedView.class)
    private byte[] content;

    public byte[] getContent() {
        System.out.println("Get content: " + Arrays.toString(content));
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(byte[] content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public int getId() {
        System.out.println("Get ID: " + id);
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Entity [id=" + id + ", content=" + Arrays.toString(content) + "]";
    }
}
```

Above program prints:

```
Generate JSON with basic properties: 
Get ID: 100
{"id":100}
Generate JSON with all properties: 
Get ID: 100
Get content: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
{"id":100,"content":"AQIDBAUG"}
```

As you can see, with basic view Jackson doesn't read `content` properties.

Comment: yeah. but I must write something like oMapper.setSerializationConfig(oMapper.getSerializationConfig()
                    .withView(View.BasicView.class));
  but in fasterxml jackson there is no setSerializationConfig method

Comment: can you provide me code of generation json with basic properties?

Comment: Why you do not want to use objectMapper.writerWithView(View.BasicView.class) method?

Comment: Thanks, I event don't know about that method. TANK YOU VERY MUCH!

Comment: Hello Michal, your solution seems amazing, but I got a little question, these view you use, you created them yourself? And simply adding an inheritance between two views means the child will also include the fields defined by the parent? If all this is true, then I owe you a lot.

Comment: Yes, I've created these views. And yes, child view contains also parent properties.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it is impossible to make jackson to lazy load your property on demand. Maybe an alternative way is to create another value object, just copy the properties you want and drop that you don't want.

Comment: but how about json viewa and custom serialization filters?

Comment: **lazy loading** is a feature of ORM tools like hibernate. you can  definitely use view and filters to customize your json string as @michal-ziober suggested.